# How can I fix this alignment?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code, I would like to remove the space above the social icons, I do not know where is taken from the /div ends before the social icons start.

Something like in this image would be desired result: http://prntscr.com/ap7ai7

```html
<strong><div style="margin-top: 10px;">© 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UID-Nummer CHE-356.597.965 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IBAN: CH25 0070 0115 8002 6948 8 ZKB - Zürich</strong></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the first div `float: left` if you want them to be in one line with the div containing social icons:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; float: left;">© 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA (...)
```

Also you should use CSS `margin` or `padding` for making spaces between elements instead of using **a lot** of `&nbsp;` entities.

For example, add a CSS class defining style for all footer text elements:

```
div.footerText {
    padding: 10px 50px 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Then change your HTML by closing all texts in seperate DIV's with this new CSS class (and remove the left padding from first one to have it on the left side):

```
<div class="footerText" style="padding-left:0"><strong>&copy; 2016 RIESEN-PRINTMEDIA</strong></div>
<div class="footerText"><strong>UID-Nummer CHE-356.597.965</strong></div> 
<div class="footerText"><strong>IBAN: CH25 0070 0115 8002 6948 8 ZKB - Zürich</strong></div>
```

You will get something similar to your current style without overusing `&nbsp;` entity, and you can easliy manipulate the spaces by modifying `padding` in CSS class.

Comment: @wilk can you give me an example of margin or padding for my above code?

Comment: @UhlHosting I updated answer with an example of how you could use padding in CSS instead of `&nbsp;`